# Modelform validates and saves successfully in view...and yet it doesn't

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

HI,

This is an unexpected result for me.  I do the following in my view....

```
        (standard view stuff here...)

        if post:
            postform=PostForm(request.POST,instance=post, prefix="post")
            tagform=TagForm(request.POST, instance=post,prefix='tags')  
            ohouse_form=Host_OHouseForm(request.POST,instance=post,prefix="ohouse")
        else:   
            postform=PostForm(request.POST,prefix="post")
            tagform=TagForm(request.POST, prefix='tags')
            ohouse_form=Host_OHouseForm(request.POST,prefix="ohouse")   

                   (....I first validate that postform and tagform are valid...) 
        if ohouse_form.is_valid():
            ohouse=ohouse_form.save(commit=False)
            ohouse.post=post
            ohouse.host=user
            ohouse.save()
```

The form in question is a modelform.  What's confusing me is that the the view is working properly in that the form validates and the save is successful.  The model should save at that point...if there were anything wrong with the form/model, it would either not validate or raise an error.

And yet the instance isn't showing up in my admin backend. It's also not present in the ohouse queryset.

This is perplexing me

Comment: How do you know that the form is validating? I mean how exactly did you check? You said the save is successful too, which I don't get: how could it be successful if it wasn't -- how are you checking. print `"ohouse saved and id is {id}".format(id=ohouse.id)` after your save line to debug... Also, have you done anything with `save()`? Sorry for the obvious, we just don't have much to go on atm.

Comment: right, so I "checked" by setting up a series of return HttpResponse statements. Debugging is a big whole in my knowledge base and so I just normally use HttpResponse to debug.  How do I print to debug? should I raise a error?

Comment: I didn't override the model or modelform save() method.  I'd add more code here but my view is massively long (it's actually a problem, I need to split it up into a series of smaller functions)

Comment: I use the dev server for debugging since it's 10x faster than production (auto reset server). It shows print statements right in the console. Another great option is dev server + `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` (let's you sniff around that line of code in a python shell). But your method would work just as well for catching one exact line.

Comment: well that line is printing the following: "ohouse saved and id is 7".  It's not showing up in my admin, though.  Also, when I try to do the following, it shows 0 queryset results.  oh=Host_OHouse.objects.all() return HttpResponse(oh)

Comment: +1 on the question for teaching me what to watch out for =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest update:

That's super promising progress. That means database writes are happening, as returning that ID is a DB query.

You should `print type(ohouse)` as well. I have a feeling you're not saving an OHouse object.

I see you're passing in `instance=post` to each of your `ModelForms`, which can't be right. That would make `Host_OHouseForm({}, instance=post)` return a new `Post` object.

I've got my bet that's the problem.

```
  if post:
        postform=PostForm(request.POST,instance=post, prefix="post")
        tagform=TagForm(request.POST, instance=post,prefix='tags')  
        ohouse_form=Host_OHouseForm(request.POST,instance=post,prefix="ohouse")
```

Comment: I think that you're absolutely right.  I'm going to try to change that now.

Comment: Well I'll eat my computer if that's not it

Comment: As always, you're right, Yuji.  I don't know why I thought that I could just throw a foreign key into the instance argument. You're help is invaluable

Comment: Got my fingers crossed it's something else then... =D You beat me to all the answers! haha

Comment: Ahaha, sorry for the runaround. I got very confused since there were no errors. I'm surprised `ModelForms` don't do a type check. There must be a reason. Look, a very old, accepted ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6702

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are using prefix. Check out the strange behaviour I noticed in this other answer.

[Python - Django - Form choicefield and cleaned_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436178/python-django-form-choicefield-and-cleaned-data/5439945#5439945)

edit:

are you meaning to set all your instance=post, even for your OHouse form?

Comment: In your example there that's expected behavior. Prefixing with "foo" would make the form field name `foo-test_field`, which didn't exist in the data you passed in. The `data` you see in the form is just whatever dict you pass the form constructor as the first argument.

Comment: hi kriegar. It looks as though my cleaned_data fields are as would be expected.  I also don't know how to remove prefixing, even if it's the source of the problem. You see, I'm saving multiple forms at the same time, so I need prefixing...right?

Comment: @Yuji ahh thanks for the explaination, that's what I was thinking but the poster never returned and I wasn't familiar with using prefixing.

Comment: @Brendan are you meaning to set all your instances=post? Can you show some more of your models maybe?

Comment: @kriegar, I just noticed that too.. that's definitely the problem. He's not saving OHouse objects. I just tested `ModelForms`, they don't do validation on the instance type passed in and happily save. Haha!

Comment: yeah kriegar, I thought that that could be an issue.

Comment: +1, though I think Yuji beat you to the answer. thanks kriegar

Comment: @Brendan i got him by 3 mins! But no worries, mine was just a guess =) Thanks and glad its working.